# Write permission running Python in Notepad++

Tags: python, permissions, notepad++

I'm using Winpython on Windows 10 and notepad++, and want to run the following Python code:

```
import wave, struct, math

sampleRate = 44100.0 # hertz
duration = 1.0       # seconds
frequency = 440.0    # hertz

wavef = wave.open('sound.wav','w')
wavef.setnchannels(1) # mono
wavef.setsampwidth(2) 
wavef.setframerate(sampleRate)

for i in range(int(duration * sampleRate)):
    value = int(32767.0*math.cos(frequency*math.pi*float(i)/float(sampleRate)))
    data = struct.pack('<h', value)
    wavef.writeframesraw( data )

wavef.writeframes('')
wavef.close()
```

However I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\robin\sound\wav_00.py", line 7, in <module>
    wavef = wave.open('sound.wav','w')
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\wave.py", line 513, in open
    return Wave_write(f)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\wave.py", line 308, in __init__
    f = __builtin__.open(f, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'sound.wav'
```

I'm running the script using `C:\Users\HP\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\python.exe -i &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;`

When I run the script outside of the Winpython folder with my registered Python installation it works fine, but I want to make use of packages that are installed in the Winpython version, so this solution is not adequate

Please could someone explain how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try running as administrator.

If you running from the windows command prompt:

- Right click windows button
- Select "Command Prompt(Admin)"
- Execute the script

Hope this helps